# onChange doesn't work when value of input clears

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a problem in handling input's value changing
so here is my code in react,onChange works but  when i clear the default value it doesn't log anything until i do another change.

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  placeholder="name"
  defaultValue={this.state.name}
  onChange={e=>console.log(e.target.value)}
/>
```

I wrote console.log  just for test.

Comment: `conosle.log` Don't you think there is a typo here

Comment: you wrote `conosle.log` instead of `console.log`

Comment: There is a typo mistake in ```console.log```

Comment: yes i changed it but still doesn't work

Comment: The ```onChange``` event occurs when the contents of the input are changed and focus is moved out from the input. When you clear the ```name``` the contents change but the focus is still on input and so it does not fire onChange event. I guess maybe this will answer your question.

You can try using ```value``` instead of ```defaultValue```

Comment: I tried that but the value is immutable and doesn't change when i use value instead of defalutValue @SanketShah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value is not changing because in reactjs component rerenders once state chages   and using `console.log` on `onChange` does not update any change in state. so you have to update the state on onChange event,

Try following, I am assuming it is class component as you have used this.state.name

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  name="name"
  placeholder="name"
  defaultValue={this.state.name || ""}
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange={e=>this.setState({name:e.target.value})}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Try with **uncontrolled** input:

```
<Form.Control
    type="text"
    placeholder="name"
    onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: I changed the code but still doesnt work the mistake happend when i wrote code here i

Comment: I've updated my code, please try again now. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thnaks but i need a default value

Answer (score 0):

Use value instead of default value:

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  placeholder="name"
  value={this.state.name || ""}
  onChange={e=>console.log(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: i wrote this code but value doesn't change in input

Comment: the value is immutable when i use value

Comment: You have to update the value instead of just logging it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an empty value instead of giving it null

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  placeholder="name"
  value={this.state.name || ""}
  onChange={e=>console.log(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: i wrote this code but value doesn't change in input

Comment: the value is immutable when i use value instead of defaultValue